# How to create a validate options for submiting data?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to submit a data after click "ok" on validate pop up, in my case i can submit data of i'm click ok, but, if i click cancel or press "esc" button, its submiting to.

*i dont know why, because this is work on another view.
I'm using Codeigniter Framework btw*

### This is Code from my problem

```
<script> $("#btn-selesai").click(function(){
    var confirm = window.confirm("Apakah kamu sudah yakin selesai?"); if(confirm)$("#form-soal").submit();}); </script>
```

### This is button for ("btn-selesai")

```
<Button id="btn-selesai" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" >Selesai </Button>
```

### And this is a form method and actions

```
<form id="form-soal" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('JawabSoal/jawabanipa'); ?>">
```

The error is, if i click OK or Done, data is submited to database correctly, but, if i click cancel or press esc, data is submited too. i want if i press esc or click cancel, just close script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return, however, is needed to pass the return value of confirm to the handler. When Cancel is clicked, false is returned, which then gets passed to the handler and this cancels the default action.

Just add return false; in else condition to stop the form submit.

```
$("#btn-selesai").click(function(){
  if(window.confirm("Apakah kamu sudah yakin selesai?")){
    $("#form-soal").submit();
  }else{
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to prevent default action of the form button.

```
<script> 
    $("#btn-selesai").click(function(e){
        e.preventdefault() // This will prevent default submit action of the form
        var confirm = window.confirm("Apakah kamu sudah yakin selesai?")
        if(confirm){
            $("#form-soal").submit()
        }
    })
</script>
```